# Conditional validation in JSON schema on nested field

Tags: json

I tried searching, but I'm not quite sure how to put this in words! The point of confusion is how "required" works in JSON schema v4.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop1": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "A": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  enum:["abc","bcd"]
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "name"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "A"
        ]
      }
    },
    "prop2": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "field": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "field"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "prop1"
  ]
}
```

Here I want to set a rule that if prop1.name=="abc" then only prop2 is required otherwise prop2 is optional, how to do that ?

Comment: prop1 is an array, so I am not sure how you can do that. If prop1 was an object with a name property, you could use anyOf to make prop2 required if prop1.name is "abc".

Comment: Yes Scottux, that is the case. I need validation on array.